# Expand div onclick and auto-collapse same div after time, unable to expand again

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/tfwqD/1/

As with the above fiddle. I can expand the div when clicked and setInterval will collapse the div after 3000ms, however attempting to click on the button again will not re-expand the div.

Here's the JS code (full JSfiddle is above):

```
function growDiv(div) {
growDiv = document.getElementById(div);
if (growDiv.clientHeight) {
  growDiv.style.height = 0;
} else {
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('.measuringWrapper');
  growDiv.style.height = wrapper.clientHeight + "px";
}
setInterval(function(){growDiv.style.height = 0},3000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the `growDiv` function name and the variable name conflict. Either change the variable name or make it local like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tfwqD/2/).

```
function growDiv(div) {
    var growDiv = document.getElementById(div);
    if (growDiv.clientHeight) {
        growDiv.style.height = 0;
    } else {
        var wrapper = document.querySelector('.measuringWrapper');
        growDiv.style.height = wrapper.clientHeight + "px";
    }
    setInterval(function () {
        growDiv.style.height = 0
    }, 3000);
    return;
}
```

---

Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/tfwqD/12/

```
var flag = false;

function growDiv(div) {
    var growDiv1 = document.getElementById(div);

    if (flag) return;
    flag = true;
    var wrapper = document.querySelector('.measuringWrapper');
    growDiv1.style.height = wrapper.clientHeight + "px";

    setTimeout(function () {
        growDiv1.style.height = '0px';
        flag = false;
    }, 3000);
    return;
}
```

I have set a flag and also modified the variable name just to make sure it works.

Cheers!!

Comment: This has worked, however after clicking the 'read more' link and letting it collapse, then clicking it again, and repeating this procedure a few times the div seems to open and close much faster, not displaying the entire div.

Comment: try setting a flag to stop the second click.

Comment: It's still behaving the same with your updated flag Jsfiddle. It just seems to ignore the flag and isnt maintaining the interval

Comment: oh the problem was right there. We need setTimeout not setInterval. setInterval executes the function repeatedly. I have modified the anwser. check...

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything right except keeping `growDiv` as both function name and variable name. Change any one any try

Updated JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tfwqD/5/